# Передача массива байт на вход методу

Tags: c#, методы, rar

Доброго времени суток. Разбираюсь с исходником одной программы, которая распаковывает rar-файлы (NUnrar - https://nunrar.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest). Так вот, как её использовать:

`RarArchive archive = RarArchive.Open(path);`

В данной строчке создаётся объект, в котором собрана первичная информация о rar файле (сколько в нём файлов внутри, запаролен ли он и т.д.) Проблема в том, что на вход методу `Open()` нужно передавать путь до файла, что для меня не очень удобно. В библиотеке есть несколько перегрузок данного метода. Вот они:

```
   `public static RarArchive Open(FileInfo fileInfo);
    public static RarArchive Open(IEnumerable<Stream> streams);
    public static RarArchive Open(Stream stream);
    public static RarArchive Open(string filePath);
    public static RarArchive Open(FileInfo fileInfo, RarOptions options);
    public static RarArchive Open(IEnumerable<Stream> streams, RarOptions options);
    public static RarArchive Open(Stream stream, RarOptions options);
    public static RarArchive Open(string filePath, RarOptions options);`
```

Мне было бы гораздо удобнее передавать на вход данной функции массив байт файла. Как это грамотнее всего сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одна из перегрузок принимает `Stream`, а его можно создать из массива байт с помощью `MemoryStream`:

```
Stream s = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
RarArchive archive = RarArchive.Open(s);
```

Comment: вот что значит невнимательность. Спасибо!